# Overlay image absolutely between 2 divs

Tags: css, image

So I have a few section with a dynamic height(Based on viewport) and I need to be able to position a img as a divider between sections. The only way I can think of to do it is to absolutely position the images. The problem is I don't always know what the fixed height of each section will be.

So is there a way to be able to add a section with positioning relative to itself without having the empty space left over from position: relative.

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.divider1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50vw - 100px);
  top: 150px;
}
.divider2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50vw - 100px);
  top: 350px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section blue"></div>
  <div class="divider1">
    <img width="200" height="100" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ace/o9d/aceo9daEi.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="section red"></div>
  <div class="divider2">
    <img width="200" height="100" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ace/o9d/aceo9daEi.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="section green"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the divider as a pseudo-element (I've used `::after`) on the section element. Position the pseudo element in relation to the section element's bottom. In this way, the height of the section can change, and the divider will be in the right place.

Note - you have to wrap the div's inside a container, so we can disable the `::after` on the last section.

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.section:not(:last-child)::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  background: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ace/o9d/aceo9daEi.jpeg) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  content: "";
  z-index: 1;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="section blue"></div>

  <div class="section red"></div>

  <div class="section green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your images have stable dimensions: width="200px" height="100px", then you can place them absolutely positioned inside colored divs and independent of parent height:

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;

}
.section img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="section blue"></div>
  <div class="section red">
     <img  src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ace/o9d/aceo9daEi.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="section green">
      <img  src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ace/o9d/aceo9daEi.jpeg" />
  </div>
```